# SN.EXE error Failed to install key pair -- Bad Version of provider

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-sdk

Recently I moved from Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 with .NET framework SDK 4.8 to VS2022 with .NET SDK 6.0. I'm no longer able to install *.snk becouse I'm getting an error:

*Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Failed to install key pair -- Bad Version of provider.*

Does anyone know what could be the issue?